# Button in label for custom file selector field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, material-ui

I'm attempting to make a custom file selector button.  So instead of having a `<input type='file'/>`  I would like to have a clickable button which does the same thing.

```
                <input
                  style={{ display: 'none' }}
                  id="raised-button-file"
                  type="file"
                  onChange={this.onFileChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
                  <Button className="shapefile-icon" component = `span`>
                    <PublishIcon/>
                  </Button>
                </label>
```

I don't understand that when i remove the `component = 'span'` this stops the button from functioning correctly.  It is no longer clickable unless i click the label area around the button.  I'm curious as to why this is working this way as well as how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than putting a `Button` inside a `label`, just have the `Button` **be** the `label` using `component="label"`.

As far as the "why" for the behavior, this is unrelated to Material-UI and behaves the same way [using a plain `<button>` element](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-input-button-7iulb). The `button` gets the "default" behavior of the click rather than the `label`. You can get a `span` to behave the same way if you call [event.preventDefault()](https://codesandbox.io/s/file-input-button-4pneq).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import PublishIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Publish";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        id="raised-button-file"
        type="file"
        onChange={() => {}}
      />
      <Button
        htmlFor="raised-button-file"
        className="shapefile-icon"
        component="label"
      >
        <PublishIcon />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit file input button]